# Buliding an API using php and json

Tags: php, json

I have the following scripts that displays database records via json. it works very fine.

My question is how do i create a secure API with it so that when users place the api say
`http://www.waco.com/profile.php?id=0990999&security=xxxxxxxxx` in their website,
it will pull the information from my server and display it on their site. below is the entire working code

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var formhtml =  "logreq=1";
    var postURL= 'profile.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postURL,
        data: formhtml,
        dataType: JSON,
        success: function(html){
            var output= '<table class="logtable"><tbody><thead><th>Log</th><th>Username</th><th>Date</th><th>Event</th></thead>';
            var logsData = $.parseJSON(html);
            for (var i in logsData.logs){
                output+="<tr><td>" + logsData.logs[i].title + "</td><td>" + logsData.logs[i].user + "</td><td>" + logsData.logs[i].date+ "</td><td>" + logsData.logs[i].log+"</td></tr>";               
            }
            //write to container div
            $("#log_container").html(output);
        },
        error: function (html) {
            alert('Oops...Something went terribly wrong');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log_container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>





<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","profile_database");
    //MSG
    $query = "SELECT * FROM logs LIMIT 20";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    //Add all records to an array
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    //Return result to jTable
    $qryResult = array();
    $qryResult['logs'] = $rows;
    echo json_encode($qryResult);

    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

please i need help.

Comment: I think what you want is to produce a feed that people can pull a JSON  string containing their data. It will be up to them to place it on their site in a particular way. If embeddable code is what you are after, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your example is an oversimplification, and that you will be looking into preventing SQL injections as well as any additional validation to ensure that you are getting the data you are expecting.

With that said, I would place your PHP code in a separate file for the user to call and drop your code into it like so:

```
if(isset($GET['id']) && isset($GET['security'])){
  $id = $GET['id']; $secure = $GET['security']; // TODO: escape these strings

  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","profile_database");
  //MSG
  $query = "SELECT * FROM logs LIMIT 20 Where id = $id And security = $secure";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  //Add all records to an array
  $rows = array();
  while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
  //Return result to jTable
  $qryResult = array();
  $qryResult['logs'] = $rows;
  echo json_encode($qryResult);

  mysqli_close($db);
}
```

Hope that helps. [This](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) is good place to start. I would also look into PHP frameworks like [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/about) or [Cake](http://cakephp.org/) that will help you build your API properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess i can use PDO against SQL Injection and htmlentities/htmlspecialchars against xxs attack.  my question is what could be the resultant API that i can send to my users to place in their site so as to be able to pull informations from my server. Am just confused.  Thank you

Comment: The "resultant API", if i am understanding you correctly, is the PHP file containing your code that securely accesses your database. You are also missing some kind of authentication mechanism that will allow you to determine if that use has rights to the data. Remember your URL? That will have to be the PHP file in question that hold your server-side code and connect to the DB.

Comment: You give user the link and they plug in their creds with the URL string: your_site.com/yourPHPFile.php?id=myId&secrurity=email or something of sorts. They then get back their data if they are in your system.

Comment: do i have to give them this link along with the eg http://www.waco.com/profile.php?id=0990999&security=xxxxxxxxx

Comment: along withi the ajax code in the head and body of html file above

Comment: Just added more required reading to help you. What i have above is just to give you an idea of you to pull data through the URL. It is NOT a finished product.